# Compatibility issue between SHAP and NumPy: TypeError with NumPyArrayGeneric

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, shap

I am encountering a compatibility issue between the SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) library and NumPy in my Python environment. The issue arises when I attempt to use SHAP to compute SHAP values for my machine learning model.

When I execute the following code:

```
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_classifier)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

I encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

The error message seems to be related to the shap.utils module and the NumPyArrayGeneric variable.

I have reinstalled SHAP to ensure a clean installation, which installed a version of NumPy.
I have verified the compatibility of SHAP and NumPy versions, but I'm still encountering this error.

SHAP version: 0.44.1

NumPy version: 0.22 (I believe)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: where exactly? Please update your post to include the full error trace - see how to creaste a [mre]

Comment: Also always provide the full error traceback.

Comment: And I assume you mean **1**.22 for numpy?